# App crashes when view controller popped from navigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am pushing an object on navigation controller but when I return the control from the that view controller it crashes the app.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chequeDetails animated:YES];
        [chequeDetails release];
```

but when I write the same code with

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chequeDetails animated:YES];
 chequeDetails=nil;
[chequeDetails release];
```

The app does not crash but a slight lag is observed... when i pop back from the check details controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your seconds exaple code, you are not release the `chequeDetails` since calling `release` on a nil object does not nothing:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chequeDetails animated:YES];
 chequeDetails=nil;
// calling the release on nill will do nothing
[chequeDetails release];
```

Normally you can do it this ways:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chequeDetails animated:YES];
[chequeDetails release], chequeDetails = nil;
```

But only release the `chequeDetails` if you did a alloc, init like:

```
ChequeDetails *chequeDetails = [[ChequeDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChequeDetails" bundle:nil];
```

So the full code should be something like:

```
ChequeDetails *chequeDetails = [[ChequeDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChequeDetails" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chequeDetails animated:YES];
[chequeDetails release], chequeDetails = nil;
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont Know Exat... but i think you need to create a object of your delegate and you need to write appDelegate.navigationController rather then self.navigationController...

Note: appDelegate is a object of Delegate.